# Use html form input to build URL that the page directs to upon submitting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am attempting to take user input from an html form and then form a URL from that input that the user is directed to upon submitting the form. Currently, I have the following html form:

```
       <form>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cityInput">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cityInput" name="cityInput">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="stateCodeInput">State Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stateCodeInput" name="stateCodeInput">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitLocation "id="submitLocation" onclick="costOfLivingURL()">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Then I have the following JavaScript function that is setting values that will make the URL, as well as building the URL:

```
    async function costOfLivingURL() {
        let searchedCity = await getCity();
        let searchedStateCode = await getStateCode();
        var currentCity = document.getElementById('cityInput').value.trim();
        var currentStateCode = document.getElementById('stateCodeInput').value.trim();
        window.location.href = "https://www.bestplaces.net/cost-of-living/" + currentCity + "-" + currentStateCode + "/" + searchedCity + "-" + searchedStateCode + "/50000";
    }
```

However, when I click on the button, nothing is happening at all.

I am not sure if my redirection is incorrect and I am also not sure if this is the correct way to use input data. If anyone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I bet something is indeed happening. The page reloads since you aren't preventing the default action of a submit button submitting the form

Comment: Remove type="submit" from your button, it should works.